# Merging set of combinations into a larger set (Reverse Combinations)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, combinations, graph-theory

I'm trying to create a function which takes a list of subsets, and merge them into larger sets if all combinations are present.

Basically, let's say we have n=4 (i.e index_domain = {0,1,2,3}) and we have the following combinations as input

```
[(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

the function should take this input and generate the following output:

```
[(0, 2, 3), (1, 3)]
```

So, (0, 2, 3) since all of the combinations (combination of 2) are present in the input list. (1, 3) remains as is since we don't have another combination of 1.

For an index domain D ⊆ ℕ and input list L, the main features of the case are:

- L can be an empty list. (Off topic)
- L always contains combination of 2s, i.e pairs, if not empty.
- The pairs are symmetric and only one of the pairs are included in L (no duplicates). That is, if a pair (i, j) should be included in L, then pair (i, j) is present in L and (j, i) is never included, where i < j and i, j ∈ D.
- There is never a pair (i, i) in L, i ∈ D.

Simply it is combinations(n, 2) in reverse. I have searched for this topic "reverse combinations", and I've yet to find an appropriate resource so far. I've considered some options like  double iteratation of the input to check if all combinations are there, but that's not the best way of doing it. I've yet to come up with an efficient solution. Appreciate any idea for an effective solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What would be the range of ```n``` here?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Well, in my situation n bounded above with 100 (at max), but generally n~20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem seems to be equivalent to the problem of finding all [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) in an undirected graph. For each pair in the input, add an edge to the graph; when there's a clique in the graph, each pair of the set of values represented by that clique's vertices is present in the input.

The bad news is that this is [a very well-known NP-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), so you probably won't find an efficient solution. The good news is that there are a lot of algorithms out there already that you can rely on to implement your solution. For example, the networkx package already implements [an algorithm to find all cliques](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html).

So, what you probably should do is:

1. convert input to graph
2. use an algorithm to find cliques
3. convert found cliques to sets

Comment: What is a clique?

Comment: @jurez This should be explained if you follow the Wikipedia link that was already present in the answer, but I've edited to add another link to the definition of a "clique" in graph theory.

Comment: @kaya3 Of course I can use Google, but I want to understand the explanation behind "the problem seems to be equivalent" in simple terms (without having to understand the entire graph theory).

Comment: @jurez Well, you asked "what is a clique?" which seems to be a request for a definition of the word "clique". I don't know what else would need to be added to make it clearer.

Comment: @kaya3 Understanding something is infinitely more than knowing the definition.

Comment: @jurez Well, as I said, the way your question was phrased, it looked like you were asking for a definition. If what you actually intended to ask was "please will you do the work of teaching me about cliques so that I can form a deep understanding of them" then the answer is "no" from me and probably "no" from anyone else here. I suggest taking the initiative and trying to learn about them yourself, if you think developing that understanding would make this answer more useful to you.

Comment: @kaya3 Forgive me for taking your time, but to me there seems to be a huge jump from pulling a purely mathematical definition from somewhere and claiming that it will solve OP's problem. I just want to hear the reasoning behind this claim. Otherwise the next time I run into a similar problem I will not be able to apply this knowledge. I also don't have time to learn all the graph theory, but that was never even the point. I believe we are here because we want to help each other become better programmers and not to solve random HackerRank assignments.

Comment: @jurez Well, from my perspective the definition of "clique" is straightforward, and the connection to the OP's problem is obvious. I realise "obvious" is relative, and I don't intend it negatively, but because it's obvious to me then I wouldn't be able to guess what addition would make it clearer to you. I'd be happy to edit this answer further if it would make it more useful to readers including yourself, but you'll have to be more specific about what needs clarifying.

Comment: @kaya3 So let me try to rephrase my question: *Can you add a short layman's explanation why the problem is equivalent to finding cliques in an undirected graph?* By "layman" I mean somebody who knows the essentials of graph theory, but not the definition of cliques.

Comment: @jurez Alright - not sure I would do a good job of that edit, but maybe the author of the answer will consider expanding it.

Comment: @jurez I agree that an intuitive explanation of why the two problems are equivalent is needed... which is why I added the second line of my original answer on how one problem translates to another. I do not see how one could explain it more intuitively than by using graph theory. I also do not see how someone that has basic knowledge of graph theory, wouldn't be able to understand this explanation. Within the context of this question, there is nothing more to understand about cliques than its definition, and how cliques in a graph correlate to all pairs of a set being part of the input.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've read about cliques and it probably would do the thing when I implement it. Through the comments I understand why @jurez wanted a clarification on the connection to the problem in the question. To me the connection is easier to appercieve with my statement in the question that "only combinations of 2s are present in the input list", and cliques by the wiki's definition is "the subset of verticies of an undirected graph where each pair of vertices are adjacent.". Concept of clique forces each pair to be adjacent, that confuses one a bit about the connection though.